# Dependency Injection Symfony object creation parameters

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have been looking up how symfony does it's [dependency injection](http://svn.symfony-project.com/components/dependency_injection/trunk/lib/). But I don't understand the direct purpose of it.

It seem to refer everything as a service. A service is something along the line of a configured router. Most of those service have a base line of set variables needed to initiation. But there is a method that's called 'isShared'.

I assume when using that method it creates a new Object instead of an Object that had been created already.

But what happens when the Object to be created needs a completely different variable?

```
class foobarClass
{
    public function __construct($config.foo)
    {
        //
    }
}

$container = new sfContainerBuilder(array('config.foo' => 'bar'));

$container->register('foobar','foobarClass')
          ->addArgument('%config.foo%')
          ->isShared(false);
```

What is config.foo shouldn't be bar but foo? Do I need to create another definition for basically every possible configuration (seems weird and defeating the purpose of the DIC)?

Also what is the main difference between a dependency injection and inverse control? What is used to what when and where?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Another example on the parameter problem:

```
class Files
{
    protected $_path;

    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->_path = $path;
    }
}

$container = new sfContainerBuilder(array('path.to.something' => '/some/path/file.abc'));

$container->register('files','files')
          ->addArgument('path.to.something')
          ->isShared(false);
```

How am I supposed to give a new path if needed? The definition already has path.to.something. But what if I need an Object with path.sto.somethingElse?

Comment: dependency injection is a way to do inversion of control. There are many other ways to do inversion of control. As for your parameters , doesnt matter since the configuration is usually read from a config file that will not change when the application is executed ( though your question is confusing because you tagged SF2 but your code looks like SF1 ).

Comment: My bad, thought it was SF2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symfony2 a service is a normal class, without a need of class inheritance.
The purpose is that you **don't need to care to initiate** the objects.
For really small applications it seems not necessary, but it can become to a problem, when you have dependencies between some objects. For example: you have 4 objects with this relations:
B -needs-> A, C -needs-> A, D -needs-> B & C

At this time it is really usefull to configure the initiation not in the inside of each class, instead you write it (in this case) into the services.xml / services.yml

Inversion of control sometimes is used in this context, it's more general. But the inversion of control is in this case (Dependency Injection) also done, because you handle the initiation outside of the objects.

**To your other question:**

> What is config.foo shouldn't be bar but foo?

You can pass parameter not in the constructor, you can pass them in another function.
Another solution when you really need a argument many times, but want also be flexible you can use also inheritance on both sides (DI and class) [documentaion for Parent Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html)

But for the first, I recommend you to read this with the `mailer` example, it's really easy: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html
Then you can continue with next pages about different types of injection, etc.